# Offload support for Intel® Graphics Technology has been removed in Intel C++ Compiler 19.0 beta

Tags: c++, opencl, openmp, gpgpu, icc

[Documentation](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-c-compiler-190-for-windows-release-notes-for-intel-parallel-studio-xe-2019#190_beta_init_options) for Intel® C++ Compiler 19.0 Beta for Windows (and Linux) claims: `Offload support for Intel® Graphics Technology has been removed`.

Can someone verify that it applies to OpenMP offload directives for Intel integrated GPUs (Intel® Graphics Technology)?

Comment: Not sure if those types of questions are welcome here. It's not really a programming question.

Comment: @Rakete1111 C++, GPGPU, OpenMP - pure programming. Granted, the question is vendor specific, as 1000s of other questions on SO are.

Comment: @EdChum `request that only Intel has the authority to answer`: 2 out of 3 questions, probably yes. `Does it apply to OpenMP offload directives?` can be answered by anyone who is using this version of icc.

Comment: Do you refer to MIC KNC?  That support was removed in the current release.

Comment: @tim18 I refer to integrated GPUs (Intel® Graphics Technology), but I didn't know about removal of offload for Xeon Phi (new marketing speak for MIC). How is one supposed to program for it?

Comment: I think this only applies to CilkPlus and not offloading in general.

Comment: Cilkplus is no longer in development for either intel or gnu compilers.  I wasn't aware that Intel might have taken away some graphics coprocessor support at the same time as intel xeon phi knc support was stopped.  Offload directive were never supported for the current xeon phi knl in spite of such being advertised in advance. Knl runs full blown linux which the coprocessor couldn't

Comment: I meant that I think the quoted line in the original question is only referring to the offload support in ClikPlus being removed. Not offloading in general.

Comment: They are probably referring to the support outlined in https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/522442

Comment: @andrew.punnett It sounds plausible, but there is no reference to Cilk Plus in that paragraph. There is a different section stating that Cilk Plus is deprecated.

Answer (score 3):

Intel(R) C++ Compiler 19.0 Release Notes clarifies the removal of Offload support for Intel(R) Graphics Technology: https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-c-compiler-190-for-linux-release-notes-for-intel-parallel-studio-xe-2019#support_removed

By using the Intel® SDK for OpenCL Application, you could achieve the same goal but it will demand a rewrite to some of your code to be offloaded. See this link (https://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-opencl/download) for the free download and how to get started.

You can use Intel(R) TBB Flow Graph which supports opencl_node when it comes to heterogeneous programming for Intel(R) Processor Graphics. More information on this available at https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2015/12/09/opencl-node-overview

Answer (score 2):

You can use [OpenMP 4.5/5.0 TARGET feature to offload computation to Intel Integrated Graphics](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/openmp-50-target-with-intel-compilers) (at this time Gen 9 through Gen 11). Although you will need to download and install the Intel oneAPI Base Toolkit AND the Intel oneAPI HPC Toolkit.